# Function recursion Maximum call stack size exceeded

Tags: javascript

I am writing the Sudoku game and having trouble finding the reason for the stack overflow. In simple words, I am filling a block with numbers 1-9 randomly. But before actually putting the number in the block, I also need to check whether there is such a number in the column it belongs to and if there is, re-random the number and check again. I've been trying a function like

```
let columns = [];
for(i = 0; i < 9; i++){
    let a = [];
    columns.push(a);
}
randomCell.textContent = unusedNumbers[getRandomNumber(0, (unusedNumbers.length - 1))];
function checkColumn() {
    if(columns[columnIndex - 1].includes(randomCell.textContent)) {
        randomCell.textContent = unusedNumbers[getRandomNumber(0, (unusedNumbers.length - 1))];
        checkColumn();
    } else {
        columns[columnIndex - 1].push(randomCell.textContent);
        unusedNumbers.splice(unusedNumbers.indexOf(randomCell.textContent), 1);
    }
}
checkColumn();
```

It should work just fine, and 2 of 3 times it does and I get a generated Sudoku with non-repeating numbers in both blocks and columns. But there are cases in which it loops endlessly somehow and reaches the maximum call stack size. I have also tried the same thing with the

```
while (1 == 1) {
    if(columns[columnIndex - 1].includes(randomCell.textContent) == false) {
        columns[columnIndex - 1].push(randomCell.textContent);
        unusedNumbers.splice(unusedNumbers.indexOf(randomCell.textContent), 1);
        break;
    }
    randomCell.textContent = unusedNumbers[getRandomNumber(0, (unusedNumbers.length - 1))];
}
```

instead of a function, but it's the same - 2 times it generates as it should, and the third time the page just freezes in an endless loop. I feel there is a small and obvious mistake in the condition which I do not see.

Edit: I get the numbers not from an RNG but from an array
`let unusedNumbers = ['1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9'];`, and after I actually pick a number after both checks, I am splicing it from the array. The RNG works with indexes here.

Comment: What happens if there's only one choice out of the nine that is viable, and the random number generator refuses to pick that one for a randomly long amount of time?

Comment: For each block, I have the array
let unusedNumbers = ['1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9'];
from which I deduct a precise number every time I actually pick it after both checks. Then the RNG gets a random item from the ones that left, so that's not a problem if I got you right.